# How to understand the notation of area element vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I've already known that the area element of vector surface integral can be written as $dA = \frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial t}dsdt$, where **r**(s,t) is a parameterization of the surface. However, the area element can also be written as $dA=dxdy \hat k + dydz \hat i + dxdz \hat j$. So, do these two forms equal? How to derive(and understand) the latter form?

Comment: Sorry, but your equations don't make any sense. The first one can be fixed by inserting the norm:$$dA= \left\|\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial t}\right\|dsdt$$

Comment: Note that even though the cross product is a vector, its norm transforms like an area. The reason is that the cross product itself depends on the choice of unit. So the formula$$dA= \left\|\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial t}\right\|dsdt$$is legit, even though one might not think so at first glance. To avoid confusion, you can use the following equivalent formula:$$dA= \left\|\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial s}\wedge\frac{\partial \textbf{r}}{\partial t}\right\|dsdt$$

Comment: Note that in the second equation, we are considering a different norm, namely the norm of an oriented area. It is given by the following formula:$$\|v\wedge w\|=\|v\|\|w\|\sin\theta=\sqrt{\det\begin{pmatrix}\langle v,v\rangle&\langle v,w\rangle\\\langle w,v\rangle&\langle w,w\rangle\end{pmatrix}}$$

Answer (score 1):

## Intro

(This section was largely copied from [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3856534/26369) to the related question [A doubt regarding change of variables in Double Integrals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3845909/26369).)

There are two main types of ways to think about things like $\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ in multivariable calculus, and we often switch between them depending on the context. (This clarification was inspired in part by Terry Tao's preprint on “[differential forms and integration](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/preprints/forms.pdf)”.) $\mathrm{d}x$ can either act kind of like a positive number representing a small length, or act kind of like a vector with a direction/[orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)) baked in.

For the “number” interpretation, there are things like limit arguments in [analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_analysis#Limits_and_convergence) or infinitesimals in [nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis) to make things rigorous. For the “vector” interpretation, there are things like “[differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form)” or “[geometric calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_calculus)” to make things rigorous. But I'm going to gloss over those details because there are *many* ways to make things formal, and the exact choices don't affect the intuition here.

## Orientation

If you care about the direction of the normal area vector $\mathrm d\mathbf A$ (e.g. because you would like to integrate $\mathbf F\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf A$ for some vector field $\mathbf F$), then we're in a situation where orientation matters.

#### Background

For instance, maybe $\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial s}\times\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial t}$ goes in the correct direction, but swapping $s$ and $t$ would give $\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial t}\times\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial s}$ which goes in the wrong direction. But this is a little weird, because an integral shouldn't care about how you labeled the parameters of the surface, as long as $\mathrm d\mathbf A$ points in the right direction in the end.

There are many ways to address this. One approach is to think about orientation *also* mattering in the parameter domain in the $st$-plane. For comparison, with regular $1$-d integrals, you can write things like $\int_4^3f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ to signify something like "integrate over $[3,4]$, but give a negative sign because we're doing it backwards". Similarly, if you think about the domain in the $st$-plane, it could be oriented positively (imagine something like $\mathrm ds\times\mathrm dt$) or negatively (imagine something like $-\mathrm ds\times\mathrm dt=\mathrm dt\times\mathrm ds$). And if $\mathrm ds\mathrm dt$ secretly meant something similar in spirit to $\mathrm ds\times\mathrm dt$ that swaps signs when the order swaps (unlike regular multiplication of numbers), then $\mathrm d\mathbf A=\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial s}\times\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial t}\,\mathrm ds\mathrm dt=\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial t}\times\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial s}\,\mathrm dt\mathrm ds$ since the two minus signs cancel out!

Across multiple different ways of formalizing things, a symbol used for this non-commutative multiplication is $\wedge$. Note that $\mathrm ds\wedge\mathrm ds=-\mathrm ds\wedge\mathrm ds$ by swapping the two factors, so that  $\mathrm ds\wedge\mathrm ds=\boldsymbol 0$, and similarly for $\mathrm dt$.

#### Verification

Let's say $\mathbf r(s,t)=\left\langle x(s,t),y(s,t),z(s,t)\right\rangle$. With this noncommutative multiplication $\wedge$ and orientation mattering, we can justify a version of your formula by using formulas like you might have seen for linear approximations of multivariable functions: e.g. $\mathrm dx=\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\mathrm{d}s+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t$. Then we have:

\begin{align}
\mathrm d\mathbf A &=\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial s}\times\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial t}\,\mathrm ds\wedge\mathrm dt\\
&=\det\begin{bmatrix}\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}} & \hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}} & \hat{\boldsymbol{k}}\\
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s} & \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial s}\\
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t} & \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t}
\end{bmatrix}\,\mathrm{d}s\wedge\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\left(\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t}-\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}}+\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}-\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t}\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}}+\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}-\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}\right)\mathrm{d}s\wedge\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}

And we also have (making sure to switch the order of the “$dxdz$” product into $\mathrm dz\wedge\mathrm dx$):

\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}+\mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}z\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}}+\mathrm{d}z\wedge\mathrm{d}x\hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}}\\&=\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\mathrm{d}s+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t\right)\wedge\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\mathrm{d}s+\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}+\cdots\\&=\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\mathrm{d}s\wedge\mathrm{d}s+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\mathrm{d}t\wedge\mathrm{d}s+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}s\wedge\mathrm{d}t+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t\wedge\mathrm{d}t\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}+\cdots\\&=\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}*0+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\mathrm{d}t\wedge\mathrm{d}s+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}s\wedge\mathrm{d}t+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}*0\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}+\cdots\\&=\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\mathrm{d}t\wedge\mathrm{d}s+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}s\wedge\mathrm{d}t\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}+\cdots\\&=\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\left(-\mathrm{d}s\wedge\mathrm{d}t\right)+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}s\wedge\mathrm{d}t\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}+\cdots\\&=\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}-\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}\,\mathrm{d}s\wedge\mathrm{d}t+\cdots=\mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}\checkmark
\end{align}
A version of this formula is mentioned in Spivak's [Calculus on Manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_on_Manifolds_(book)) and quoted in the question [Calculating Surface Area using Differential Forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4098098/26369).

## Numbers

If you *don't* care the direction of the normal area vector $\mathrm d\mathbf A$ (e.g. because you would like to integrate $\mathbf f\Vert\mathrm d\mathbf A\Vert$ for some scalar field $\mathbf f$), then orientation doesn't matter, and we really just care about the length of $\mathrm d\mathbf A$.

#### Background

If you just cared about volume under the graph of a scalar function, you might imagine adding up volumes of rectangular boxes, and you'd always write single integrals in an [iterated integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_integral) with increasing bounds (like $\int_{0}^5\int_{-1}^1f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$ since \int_{5}^0 would obviously give the wrong sign). In this sort of context, something like $\mathrm dx$ would represent a small length, and $\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$ would be the area of small rectangle in (or parallel to) the $xy$-plane.

With this kind of setup, we have to give up on an idea like $\mathrm dx=\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\mathrm{d}s+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t$ since the expression on the right couldn't represent a length if the partials were negative. And $\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}+\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}}+\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}z\hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}}$ would have three positive components, and so it would always point towards the [first octant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octant_(solid_geometry)), even if that's not either direction of $\pm\mathrm d\mathbf A$. But it turns out that we can show that it has the right length under this interpretation anyway.

#### Verification

Let's say $\mathbf r(s,t)=\left\langle x(s,t),y(s,t),z(s,t)\right\rangle$.

First, let's consider the simple case when $z(s,t)$ is a constant $z_0$. Then $\mathrm dA=\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}-\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}$ with length $\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}-\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)^2$.

Since $z(s,t)$ is constant, $\mathrm dz$ (a small change in the $z$ coordinate as we move along the surface) is $0$, so the candidate vector reduces to $\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}$. Now, if we had to integrate $f(x,y,z)$  along the surface, we could substitute in $z=z_0$ and worry about $\int f\left(x,y,z_0\right)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$ for $(x,y)$ in the projection of the surface. By [multivariable substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables)/[change of variables](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx), we could use a [Jacobian determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) to rewrite $$\int f\left(x,y,z_0\right)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\int f\left(x(s,t),y(s,t),z_0\right)\,\left|\det\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}&\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\\\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\end{bmatrix}\right|\mathrm ds\mathrm dt\text{.}$$
In other words, $$\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\left|\det\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}&\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\\\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\end{bmatrix}\right|\mathrm ds\mathrm dt=\left|\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}-\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right|\mathrm ds\mathrm dt\text{.}$$ Thus, $\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}=\pm\mathrm d\mathbf A$ and the length is still $\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}-\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)^2$.$\checkmark$

Now, consider the general case. Assuming $\mathbf r$ is nice and $\Delta s$ and $\Delta t$ are small, the four points $\mathbf r(s,t)$, $\mathbf r(s+\Delta s,t)$, $\mathbf r(s,t+\Delta t)$, and $\mathbf r(s+\Delta s,t+\Delta t)$ will approximate the vertices of a parallelogram.

It's a geometric fact that I won't reprove here that the square of the area of a parallelogram in 3D space is the sum of the squares of the areas of the projections onto the three coordinate planes. (A natural generalization is proven in [Beyond Monge's Theorem: A Generalization of the Pythagorean Theorem](https://doi.org/10.1080/0025570X.2000.11996856). And this specific case is mentioned in [Mikhail Katz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72694/mikhail-katz)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/905061/26369) to [Is it true that $d\textbf{S} = dy dz\textbf{ i }+ dx dz\textbf{ j }+ dx dy\textbf{ k }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/905026/26369). A closely related fact is shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2579400/26369) to [Area of projected parallelogram onto a plane.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2578976/26369))

For each coordinate plane, an argument like the one I gave for the constant $z(s,t)$ case applies in discussing the area element of the projection onto that plane. So the three components of $\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\hat{\boldsymbol{k}}+\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z\hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}}+\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}z\hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}}$ have the right squares for the length to equal the length of $\mathrm d\mathbf A$, as desired.